# Strategies for sourcing multiple .R files before packaging

Tags: r, package

My team and I are hoping to release several git repos. filled with .R scripts that have dependencies both across .R scripts and across the repos.

We are eventually hoping to wrap these repos up into nice packages, but development is still very active, with new files being generated and re-named often.

At the same time, pressure is strong to release what we have now.

Our current fix, instead of hard-coding `source()` commands throughout our functions, is to pass `sourceMe` arguments into them.

We are worried about security and stability on this front: we don't really want people to have the ability to source whatever they want from within our functions.

Does anybody have any recommendations for a solution given this context?